# Unnecessary casting to object used for calling ToString() in mscorlib

Tags: c#, object, resharper, virtual, tostring

In `StringWriter` (*mscorlib.dll*) I found a code:

```
private StringBuilder _sb;
// (...)
public override string ToString()
{
  return ((object) this._sb).ToString();
}
```

I don't see reason for that (so is my R#, but it is sometimes wrong). `ToString()` is `virtual` so the casting does not change behaviour.

What kind of optimization is being done here?

Comment: What I get by decompiling `StringWriter` class is: `return this._sb.ToString();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference and there is no optimization. The generated IL with and without cast is exactly the same. In fact when opening mscorlib with Reflector, it only says `return this._sb.ToString();`.

As you said, `ToString()` is `virtual`, and it is not marked `new` in `StringWriter`, so the generated IL refers to `Object.ToString()` (the initially declared method) in any case (except for some basic value types):

```
ldfld class System.Text.StringBuilder System.IO.StringWriter::_sb
callvirt instance string System.Object::ToString()
```

Even looking at the CLI 2.0 Source Code, the code is the following:

```
public override String ToString() {
    return _sb.ToString();
}
```

The only difference according to Reflector is that `StringBuilder.ToString()` is `unsafe`. There is no keyword for this in IL, but it can be found out by checking for unsafe instructions. R# might consider this a difference (although it's not) and prefer to go explicit.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of optimization is being done here?

None. R# is just wrong here.

Neither [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) nor [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) show this strange cast, and I also don't find it in the [reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).

So the code is just

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this._sb.ToString();
}
```